# Transform cos to e function

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant, multigrid

What are the steps in order to transform the cosine function to the exponential function:

$$
\left[\cos \left(\frac{k \pi} N\right)\right]^n \approx 
e ^ {\frac{-n}2 \left(\frac{k \pi} N \right)^2}
$$
if I know that 
$$
0 < k/N \ll 1
$$

I just want to understand this step. I am aware of the Euler's formula, yet I can't figure out, how to use it. The article I am reading is [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/people/irad/online-publications/Yav06.pdf)

Comment: Probably $$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4) = e^{-x^2/2} + O(x^4).$$

Comment: The sentence immediately following equation 8 in the reference you linked says "where we can verify the approximation by using a Taylor series expansion", which confirms @DanielFischer's guess.

Comment: thx, i obviosly can't read